# Update database with checkbox values retrieved from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update database table regarding to checkbox state or values.
Here below I retrieve the checkbox states from database.

When user access this page sees the current states of checkboxes.

HTML

```html
<form name="financial_checks" method="post" action="cbchange.php" />
   <input name="provision" type="checkbox" <?php if ($podata_provision == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
   <input name="invoice" type="checkbox" <?php if ($podata_invoice == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
   <input name="payment" type="checkbox" <?php if ($podata_payment == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
   <button type="submit" name="updatebtn" id="btn" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
```

I want to update table without refreshing while user change the state of checkbox, so I'm using Ajax to POST data;

```
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cbchange.php',
        data: { provision:provision, invoice:invoice, payment:payment, sendtoken:sendtoken2},


    } );
```

(sendtoken is a variable retrieved in HTML page, also I can't post)

cbchange.php

```
$provision = $_POST['provision'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$sendtoken = $_POST['sendtoken2'];


$query = " UPDATE podata SET provision = '".$provision."', invoice = '".$invoice."',payment = '".$payment."' WHERE token2 = '".$sendtoken."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

When I var_dump($_POST) result is related with the state of checkbox checked or unchecked.

```
array (size=3)
'provision' => string 'on' (length=2)
'invoice' => string 'on' (length=2)
'updatebtn' => string '' (length=0)
```

How can I post data as 1 or 0 when user change the checkbox state?

Comment: Please show how you define the javascript variables used

Comment: Also fairly trivial to check each value in php and change `'on'` to `1` and empty string to zero

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't define any variables, doesn't data pulled by checkbox name?

Comment: Huh?? What are `provision` , `invoice` and `payment`? Those are variables

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong, thought you mean any other Javascript variables. They are fetched from SQL query and assigned to their variables. 
Current data retrieved from database.

Comment: I do mean the javascript variables with those names

Comment: I'm not much familiar with Javascript so please forgive me, when I checked the other examples, I see values posted by name. I didn't see any other variable defines on examples. So I didn't do that. Is that the reason not posting as 1 or 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value attribute of the input.

`<input name="provision" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($podata_provision == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>`

as you can get the value only if it is checked but if you want them to be either 1 or 0 then stop posting the checkbox values and use `hidden` fields to keep the status and manipulate them by Jquery on checkbox status change event.

See if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I added hidden fields as below;
<input name="provision" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($podata_provision == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> id="provision"/>
<input name="provision" type="checkbox" value="0" <?php if ($podata_provision == '0')  ?> id="provision" style="display:none;"/>
But It posts only when I change states to 1. I need states to be posted because it will change the data in database.

Comment: Can you vote-up and accept the answer if this worked for you?